# Dynamic href when generating buttons?

Tags: php, html

I have a table that is displaying data to the user and each row in the table has a unique id, in the table I am generating a button for each row to get more information on the content in the row. However, i need to generate a unique href for each button based on the Unique ID of the data in the row. The way I have done it it correctly goes to the link in the href but without passing the Unique ID.

```
<tbody>
      <?php while($row = $query->fetch()) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['car_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['car_make']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['car_model']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['number_available']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['rent_cost_per_day']; ?></td>

       <td><a class="btn btn-default" href="cars.php?"<?php $row['car_id']; ?>>View</a></td>



      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
```

Any help?

Comment: If you open your generated html you will see what's wrong

Comment: You have to name the parameter `"cars.php?id=<?php $row['car_id']; ?>"` and put it *inside* the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you put the `php` after you closed the `href` quotes. You also have not put an `echo` function for the `php`, and have not put a get variable. You have:

```
href="cars.php?"<?php $row['car_id']; ?>
```

What you want to have is:

```
href="cars.php?id=<? echo $row['car_id']; ?>"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @xiimoss no problem.